# Split and Format Date Range

Tags: python, pandas, zapier

I am working on parsing a date range from an email in zapier. Here is what comes in: Dec 4 - Jan 4, 2020 From this I need to separate the start and end date to something like 12/04/2019 and 01/04/2020 accounting for the fact that some dates will start in the prior year as in the example above and some will be in the same year for example Mar 4 - Mar 22, 2020. It seems the code to use in zapier is python. I have looked at examples for panda

```
    import pandas as pd
    date_series = pd.date_range(start='Mar 4' -, end='Mar 7, 2020')
    print(date)
```

But keep getting errors. 
Any suggestions would be much appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it:

```
def parse_email_range(date_string):
    dates = date_string.split(' - ')

    month_1 = pd.to_datetime(dates[0], format='%b %d').month
    month_2 = pd.to_datetime(dates[1]).month

    day_1 = pd.to_datetime(dates[0], format='%b %d').day
    day_2 = pd.to_datetime(dates[1]).day

    year_2 = pd.to_datetime(dates[1]).year
    year_1 = year_2 if (month_1 < month_2) or (month_1 == month_2 and day_1 < day_2) else year_2 - 1

    return '{}-{}-{}'.format(year_1, month_1, day_1), '{}-{}-{}'.format(year_2, month_2, day_2)

parse_email_range('Dec 4 - Jan 4, 2020')

## ('2019-12-4', '2020-1-4')
```

Comment: Hi @Oriol I tried running this but I am getting an invalid syntax error for line 13         return pd.date_range(start=f'{year_1}-{month_1}-{day_1}', end=f'{year_2}-{month_2}-{day_2}') also how would I return just the start and end date verses the range

Comment: What python version are you running? If you have a python version earlier than 3.6, then you don't have f-strings and you need to format the dates differently. Let me know (or post the whole error so that I can see what the issue is). As for getting only the beginning and the end of the range, then you don't need to return the range, but only the two values. What exactly do you want the function to return? A tuple with the start and end of the range? A list? A pandas series? It's not difficult to do, but you need to know what you need.

Comment: Its running version 3.7. Just need it to return the start and end date only formatted as %Y-%m-%d. Here is the error: 'Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python3.4/pdb.py", line 1661, in main pdb._runscript(mainpyfile)  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/pdb.py", line 1542, in _runscript self.run(statement) File "/usr/lib/python3.4/bdb.py", line 431, in run exec(cmd, globals, locals) File "<string>", line 1, in <module> File "/home/main.py", line 14 return pd.date_range(start=f'{year_1}-{month_1}-{day_1}', end=f'{year_2}-{month_2}-{day_2}') SyntaxError: invalid syntax'

Comment: I modified the answer to return only the two dates as strings. Let me know if you're still getting errors.

Comment: Still getting the error  File "main.py", line 14                                                                                                                      
    return f'{year_1}-{month_1}-{day_1}', f'{year_2}-{month_2}-{day_2}'                                                                        
                                       ^                                                                                                       
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Weird that you would see that if you're on python 3.7. It might not be the f-string. In any case, I made a change now to use the old formatting syntax. Let me know if you still have problems.

Answer (score 0):

Split the two dates and record them into a single variable:

```
raw_dates = 'Dec 4 - Jan 4, 2020'.split(" - ")
```

`dateutil` package is capable of parsing most dates:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
```

Parse and separate start and end date from the raw dates:

```
start_date, end_date = (parse(date) for date in raw_dates)
```

`strftime` is the method that could be used to format dates.

Store desired format in a variable (please note I have used day first format):

```
date_format = '%d/%m/%Y'
```

Convert the end date into the desired format:

```
print(end_date.strftime(date_format))

'04/01/2020'
```

Convert start date:

`dateutil`'s `relativedelta` function will help us to subtract one year from the start date:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

adjusted_start_date = start_date - relativedelta(years=1)

print(adjusted_start_date.strftime(date_format))

'04/12/2019'
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this and post back

Comment: Thank you, this solves the first part of my issue perfectly -if a date range falls between 2 different years for example Dec 4 - Jan 4, 2020. But it doesn't solve when the date range is in the same year for example Mar 4 - April 4, 2020. Any suggestions on how to have it solve both scenarios?

Comment: @John what criteria you're using to differentiate whether the month is of current year or last year?

Comment: That is what I have been trying to figure out. I am thinking something like: 'if '%m' == '12' in 'start_date' and '%m' != '12' in 'end_date':
  print (adjusted_start_date.strftime(date_format))
else:
  print (start_date.strftime(date_format))'         But this code does not actually work any suggestions?

Comment: Basically the only time this would occur is if the start date is in Dec and the end date is in a different month